# How to insert rows on sheet 2 upon value change on sheet 1

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of states that have statuses on sheet 1.
I'm basically trying to get data from Sheet 1, to populate onto Sheet 2 based on certain criteria. For example, If the status on Sheet 1 changes to ‘G’ on any of the states, I'm trying to get the entire row to populate into the table on Sheet 2. I'm looking to have a running table on sheet 2, so as we add information onto sheet 1, it automatically shows the breakdown of criteria on sheet 2.

It should repopulate sheet 2 with new breakdowns every time I run the script

eg.

### Sheet 1

States    status

CA        G

TX        IP

### Sheet 2

States in G

CA     G

States in IP

TX     IP

Comment: Have you looked into the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro? Can you show what you've accomplished so far (working or not)?

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd best insert a classic PivotTable with Sheet1 as the main data source. The PivotTable can be set to group your data as you wish.

Comment: That was a great suggestion. The only issue is that it creates a treeview like report that I am not able to customize.

Comment: Have you tried to use the classic view instead of the new default one? That will make it look much more like a normal sheet with rows. You can change the markup for fields etc.